# I require help on getting an HTML web layout to work correctly

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I am working with a system that creates technical reports, and I have been tasked to convert these to html which can be displayed in e-mails. Due to the limitations of e-mails I have crafted a system that uses a nested table layout to correctly place the items, and it appears to work for many use cases, however I have hit a problem that I don't know how to fix.

I have two examples where the table layout doesn't appear to be working correctly for me, which are actually two parts of the same output. The first can be found at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LywjJV and demonstrates how my objects aren't aligning correctly, as can be seen by the gaps (which should not be present) between the entries. The second example is larger, can be found at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbozVj and demonstrates further my issues with alignment.

I apologise for the code-pen links but my html is verbose as it is machine generated to try and replicate absolute positioning with tables. Unfortunately it is too long to include in the body, so there are external links.

To summarise the placement issues that I am requiring help with:

1. Both examples have a "padding column" to the left that has a defined width of `36.135pt` but appears to be removed in the actual output.
2. The objects are not all flush to  each other, resulting in a disjointed look; instead they should form appear to form one solid block.
3. In the second example the first three columns on the left have a shorter height than the following columns (it appears that each element is adding a little bit of height to the output unintentionally, even when I removed the padding styling on the elements).

Some notes about limitations etc...

1. I need to use a table layout system, despite the terrible form, so that the html will display in e-mail.
2. The css properties `table-layout`, `max-width`, `max-height` and `overflow` are not supported by Outlook, so any solution using these is not optimal (though still useful as I can rely on the "display in browser" fall-back if necessary).
3. Html e-mail does not support absolute or relative positioning in any useful fashion, so any solution revolving around using those is not going to be helpful.

I'm sorry for the ramble, but this is quite a complicated issue and I wanted to provide as much information as possible. I hope one of you can help me, and any advice is appreciated.

Comment: A few things that's wrong with the email: *Too many tables, * Each table should have cell padding and cell spacing to zero, * Border for tables have to be zero, * Remove the heights for the cells. Now consider building the both the emails (from the links) first then put it in your system that generates the code. Email troubleshooting gets hard if you are using more than 50 mini tables to do layouts.

Comment: With regards to the cell padding and cell spacing, I tried adding that to all tables, but it made no difference, I believe this is due to setting the `table{border-collapse:collapse;}` in the style.

Second I can't remove the borders from the elements as users may have borders defined for specific reasons in their reports, that I have to then honour.

Third I'm not certain I can remove the heights from the cells either, as again a user could define a very large textbox/cell that has a small amount of text, 
_Continued in next comment_

Comment: _Continued from previous comment_ where the height is needed to ensure it displays correctly. If you have an alternative solution that allows the height to be correctly set elsewhere, then I'd be happy to hear that.

Now you mention too many tables, and I don't disagree with you, however I'm not certain I can cut it down much as it needs to be a generic system that can handle whatever the user provides. I could maybe remove the tables around the individual cells, but I'm not certain.

I'm afraid I don't understand your last point about building both emails first, could you elaborate?

Comment: If you are sending this as an email then your email will contain all the codes needed to display the email the way **you** want it to. Users can not define a table border, cell spacing or cell padding on their email clients. border-collapse works the similar way as having cell padding and spacing to zero. For heights you can use padding (not cell padding) on the cells to give it a look. Lastly every email can be coded like a template, you create the email first then use your system to plugin bits of HTML to get the look right. Made sense?